# H2 DB with datetime2

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, h2

I'm trying to set up an embedded database H2 in an project that I took over.
Now we have an sql server with a column value type `datetime2`.

H2 can't create the column with type `datetime2`, if I change it to normal `datetime` then all goes correct but of course the project itself gives problems cause hibernate annotation is wrong because the DB column is a `datetime2`.

the code :

```
@Column(name = "LASTUPDATETIME", columnDefinition = "datetime2 DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
private Timestamp timeStamp;
```

Can this be done with H2(changing annotation for testing or let H2 accept datetime2) or do I have to search for another embedded database?

Comment: The H2 database does not currently support the data type `datetime2`. However, support for it was [added to the trunk now](https://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/detail?r=5595) and will be available in the next release.

Comment: Thx for the reply Thomas, pitty its only a comment cause this I should accept as answer. Thx for the fast feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The H2 database does not currently support the data type `datetime2` (as of version 1.3.176). However, support for it [was added to the trunk](https://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/detail?r=5595) now and will be available in the next release.

So, if you want to use H2 now, then you would either use a newer version (you could build it yourself for example), or change to `datetime` until you are using a newer version.

Comment: It seems that datetime2 is up to this day still not supported.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Date column type should work for you, datetime2 is a Microsoft specific data type. I've seamlessly migrated applications from MS SQL Server to H2 database before, I had to change the annotation of course, but calculations etc. were not affected.

Comment: I get what you point to, but how can I change the columnDefinition? (mine fault not to include into the question)

Comment: The big daddy of H2 himself gave you the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly tangential. `DATETIME2` is supported in H2, but `DATETIME2(7)` (or any other precision value) is no longer working as-of H2 4.197.